# Creating tabs for each name in a list

Tags: python, list, user-interface, tabs, pyqt

I am trying to figure out how I can implement my code to allow me to create a tab based on a string list and output each tab with the correct corresponding parameters/data for that tab.

A little background on this program before we keep going. The program is a text/log comparison tool I use to compare many configurations for devices against a default/correct configuration. If there are any parameters that are incorrect with the device when compared it will output the incorrect parameters to let me/user know.

But for the sake of this portion of the code lets just say we're comparing some animals.

Heres a preview of what I currently have has a GUI/Program:
[image: GUI Preview]

Essentially my goal is to have the `<Cat> <Dog> <Bird> <Tiger>` all within their own tab with their data.

The code I have been working with is the following:

```
 with open(compareResults, 'wb') as fdout:
            while (count < (len(setNames))):
                for number, item in enumerate(lst, 0):
                    print setNames[count]
                    fdout.write('{}'.format(setNames[count]) + '\r\n')
                    for param, correct in correct_parameters.items():
                        if item.get(param) != correct:
                            print ('{} = {}'.format(param, item.get(param)))
                            fdout.write('{} = {}'.format(param, item.get(param)) + '\r\n')
                    count += 1
```

The List that holds each name for each animal is `setNames[]`
If you would like to view the whole code click on the pastebin link; http://pastebin.com/6v86qgj3

My idea was to, somehow, create a loop with `setNames` that will allow me to make a tab for each name in `setNames` and then output the results to each corresponding name. However, I am not that good with PyQt and I am still trying to figure out how to make individual tabs and if I can even create this without first having to make a function for the tabs or something in this nature. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all apologies, I only have PySide installed here but it shouldn't make a difference. Here's an example of a widget that has tabs created by an array:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # Create a QTabWidget where all the tabs will be held
        self.myTabs = QtGui.QTabWidget()

        # Loop through our animal names
        setNames = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Tiger']
        for tabName in setNames:
            # Each tab needs its own widget, so let's create one with a label
            tabWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
            tabLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Hello! I am a {0}.'.format(tabName) )

            # Set the tab widget's layout
            tabLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
            tabLayout.addWidget(tabLabel)
            tabWidget.setLayout(tabLayout)

            # Create the tab
            self.myTabs.addTab(tabWidget, tabName)

        # Set the main layout
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.myTabs)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        # Resize our window and show it
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.show()

win = Window()
```

You can see it's fairly straight forward. If you ever need to access a tab's widget again, you can use `QTabWidget.currentWidget()` or `QTabWidget.widget(<index>)`.

Comment: Hi, Your code works fine on standalone but when trying to implement it into my own I get this error `AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'addTab'` But we're on the right track

Comment: Be careful that you're not trying to run `addTab()` on a `QtGui.QWidget`, but on a `QtGui.QTabWidget`

Comment: Okay that fixed the issue. Now it's a matter of where to place the code within my loop so I can correctly print out the results